# Security Error Loading Local Xml File

Tags: html, xml, actionscript-3, flash

This was working fine the last time I tried it a few days ago, but I am getting a strange error now. I have Xamp running with this file in htdocs call YAM.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VAST version="2.0">
    <Ad id="TEST">
        <InLine>
            <AdSystem version="3.1">Test</AdSystem>
            <AdTitle>JVAM Test</AdTitle>
            <Impression></Impression>
            <Creatives>
                <Creative sequence="1">
                    <Linear>
                        <Duration>00:00:15</Duration>
                        <MediaFiles>
                            <MediaFile delivery="progressive" width="640" height="480" scalable="1" type="video/mp4">
                                <![CDATA[http://127.0.0.1/YAM.swf?someVar=123344&vastUrl=http://127.0.0.1/Yashi200_15sec.mp4&vastUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fad4.liverail.com%2F%3FLR_PUBLISHER_ID%3D1331%26LR_SCHEMA%3Dvast2-vpaid&domainName=developers.google.com&fallbackVastUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fad4.liverail.com%2F%3FLR_PUBLISHER_ID%3D1331%26LR_SCHEMA%3Dvast2]]>
                            </MediaFile>
                            </MediaFiles>
                        <VideoClicks>
                            <VideoClick>
                                <ClickThrough>
                                    <![CDATA[http://www.cats.com]]>
                                </ClickThrough>
                            </VideoClick>
                        </VideoClicks>
                    </Linear>
                </Creative>
            </Creatives>
        </InLine>
    </Ad>
</VAST>
```

Also, my crossdomain.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm entering the path to this VAST xml (http://127.0.0.1/YAM.xml) into a VAST validator in the browser like the one here: http://zutils.zedo.com/vastvalidator/

For some reason when I try test the ad it gives this error:

> *** Security Sandbox Violation *** Connection to tmp/
>  **Warning**:  file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1/YAM.xml): failed
>   to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server
>   Error  in
>   **/home/adwww/apache/htdocs/adwww/vastvalidator/createxmlfile.php**
>   on line **3**
>  zedoxml144583131.xml halted - not permitted
>   from
>   http://zutils.zedo.com/vastvalidator/ova.jwplayer.5x/dist/swf/5.9.swf
>   Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Task Queue failed at step 0: Error
>
> ## 2048: Security sandbox violation: http://zutils.zedo.com/vastvalidator/ova.jwplayer.5x/dist/swf/5.9.swf
>
> cannot load data from tmp/
>  **Warning**: 
>   file_get_contents(http://127.0.0.1/YAM.xml): failed to open stream:
>   HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error  in
>   **/home/adwww/apache/htdocs/adwww/vastvalidator/createxmlfile.php**
>   on line **3**
>  zedoxml144583131.xml.

The local server is running, and if I put http://127.0.0.1/YAM.xml into my address bar I see the xml file.

I have been banging my head against the wall for a few days so if someone sees the problem please help. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

127.0.0.1 is localhost, the server cannot reach you (your file) through that IP.

Comment: But why was it able to reach my file a few days ago?

Comment: Because you did something differently. It cannot reach 127.0.0.1 You need a static IP (that is not localhost) or a DNS to make an IP publicly available.